# How to show MenuController of UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uimenucontroller, uipasteboard

How could I reproduce the copy paste function of say, Messages on iPhone, where if you long press on a message, the message cell goes gray-ish and a little pop-up with "copy" shows up. How can I show that same menu on my UICollectionViewCells?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/AddingCustomEditMenuItems/AddingCustomEditMenuItems.html ?

Comment: @Larme, consider turning that into an answer by elaborating more.

Comment: @Larme that's pretty much it, thanks

Comment: I actually can't get the menu to show up :( Should I make another thread or can I update my question with the code?

Comment: @Quantaliinuxite Update your question with your current code.

Comment: @Larme I figured it out, going to post my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out he functionality is already built in and is as simple as implementing three `collectionView:` delegate methods. I created a protocol `CopyableCell` with a property called `copyableProperty`, the string that a cell wants to copy to the clipboard, that the cells that I can copy must follow. It was straightforward from then on:

```
  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldShowMenuForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    if let _ = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? CopyableCell {
      return true
    }
    return false
  }
  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, canPerformAction action: Selector, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, withSender sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    if action.description == "copy:" {
      return true
    }

    return false
  }

  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, performAction action: Selector, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, withSender sender: AnyObject?) {
    //No more checking is needed here since we only allow for copying
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? CopyableCell {
      UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string = cell.copyableProperty
    }
  }
```